# Need to extract millions of rows from multiple tables in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have to extract millions of rows from 21 SQL tables for a list of strings. Additionally, My query has got group-by concatenation, etc.
I need to run this in a memory-friendly manner using chunks. I am using python2.
Can anyone suggest a solution?
Say here is my query, just an example.

```
query = """
        SELECT
            v.id AS varid,
            v.chrom AS chrom,
            v.vcf_pos AS vcf_pos,
            v.vcf_ref AS vcf_ref,
            v.vcf_alt AS vcf_alt,
            group_concat(distinct term.term) as HPO_terms,
            group_concat(distinct term.name) as HPO_names,
            group_concat(distinct pp.patientid,"-",pp.person_status,"-",pp.affected_status) as family_label,
          
            if(vcc.AF_Pat between 0 AND 1, vcc.AF_Pat, NULL) AS AF_Pat,
            replace(vcc.analysistypelist,',',';') AS analysistypelist,
            vcc2.HomPatCount AS AC,
            vcc2.HetPatCount AS HAC,
            vcc2.TotalPatCount AS TAAC,
            if(vcc2.AF_Pat between 0 AND 1, vcc2.AF_Pat, NULL) AS AF_Assay,
            vcc3.HomUnaffCount AS HCC,
            vcc3.HetUnaffCount AS HCC1,
            vcc3.TotalUnaffCount AS TTCC,
            if(vcc3.AF_healthy between 0 AND 1, vcc3.AF_healthy, NULL) AS AF_Control,
            g.gene_name as gene_name,
            t.tx_name as tx_name,
            ta.*,
            va.*,
            vc.*,
            ga.*,
            group_concat(
                concat_ws(':', ifnull(g.gene_name,'.'), ifnull(t.tx_name,'.'), ifnull(ta.hgvsc,'.'), ifnull(ta.hgvsp,'.'))
                SEPARATOR '|'
            ) as `AllTranscriptAnnotations`
        FROM {} AS v
            LEFT JOIN table1 vcc ON vcc.variant_id=v.id
            LEFT JOIN table2 vcc3 ON vcc3.variant_id=v.id
            LEFT JOIN table3 va on v.id=va.variant_id and va.status='active'
            LEFT JOIN table4 vc on v.id=vc.variant_id
            LEFT JOIN table5 ta on v.id=ta.variant_id and ta.status='active'
            LEFT JOIN table6 t on t.id=ta.transcript_id and t.status='active'
            LEFT JOIN table7 g on g.id=t.gene_id and g.status='active'
            .
            .
            .
            LEFT JOIN table21 pt on pt.term_id=term.id
        GROUP BY v.id,s.id
        HAVING 1 {}
        """.format(v1,sq)
```

Where `v1` and `sq` are search  strings.
Now, I need to make the above query memory efficient or optimized currently it takes more than 4 hours to finish extracting.
I am looking for something along the lines of divide and conquer chunks.

Comment: Does `v` control the rows?  That is, are all the `LEFT JOIN` delivering exactly 1 row (optionally all NULLs)?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `OFFSET`; it will be slower and slower as you go through the table.

I would consider chunking on `v.id`:

```
WHERE v.id >    0 AND v.id <= 1000   -- in first run
WHERE v.id > 1000 AND v.id <= 2000   -- 2nd
(etc)
```

More on chunking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

That link has some tricks to deal with variants (such as big gaps in `id`).

Is the `GROUP_CONCAT()` really needed?  This implies that at least some of the `LEFT JOINs` are delivering more than one row.  In this case, which tables?  (This may lead to an optimization that involves getting rid of both the `GROUP_CONCAT and the` GROUP BY`.)